# Unable to setup a connection between Visual Studio Online "Monaco" and Team Service because of (Invalid Client ID)

Tags: git, azure, tfs, azure-devops, visual-studio-monaco

I create a GIT repo in VisualStudio.com and a Web App in Azure, but when I try to Connect my Azure Web App from Visual Studio Online "Monaco" to a Team Service (GIT).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LydhY.png)

I have the following problem:

"We were unable to setup the connection because the client application did not pass the expected values to Visual Studio Team Services. Please contact them and provide the following message (Invalid Client ID)."

I have not idea how give permission in VisualStudio.com to my Azure Web App.

Comment: Can you share your steps? I cannot reproduce this issue at my side.

Comment: It was because I had a free trial subscription. After change for a payed subscription, it works. Thanks!